# xlsread error MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

I am loading an excel file into MATLAB. I need only select values.

A1=xlsread('freq1.xls','B2:B4')

But the command window outputs the whole column with a warning: Warning: Could not start Excel server for import, 'basic' mode will be
used. Refer to HELP XLSREAD for more information.

> In xlsread at 176
>     In bkh at 1
>   Warning: Range cannot be used in 'basic' mode.  The entire sheet will be
>   loaded. 
>   In xlsread at 184
>     In bkh at 1

How can I get the specific values?

Comment: Probably you know this, but just in case: If something like this is mentioned `Refer to HELP XLSREAD for more information` then it means that you should enter `help xlsread` in the command prompt to get the more info about the function.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbe6) you can't read a specific range in `'basic'` mode and if you do not have Excel installed on your computer then it defaults to `'basic'` mode. So I guess your options are either install Excel, or read in the entire page and select your range from the resulting Matlab matrix rather than from the Excel sheet.